# Proper way to update UI from a class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android development and I would like to know what is the best practice to update the UI from another class.

Example: When I enter an activity I start a function `myClass.PerformCalculation()` which takes some time, when the calculation is over I want to update the UI with the result of the calculation. 
This generates the following error:

```
CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I was thinking about using a Broadcast Receiver in the activity and perform a `SendBroadcast` at the end of `myClass.PerformCalculation()`, is it a good practice?

Comment: you should return the calculation result to the activity and update the UI in the activity. Don't use broadcasts

Comment: Thank you for the feedbacks. Based on the documentation ASyncTask seems to be the correct method to use in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the documentation to [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

It will help you to do some background tasks, and publish the result when finished to the main UI.

From the documentation:

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the
>   UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

**Example of code:** from [Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525388/asynctask-in-android-with-kotlin)

```
inner class someTask() : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String? {
        // ...
    }

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        // ...
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        // UPDATE UI HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava):

```
object MyClass {
    fun performCalculation(): Single<Int> {
        return Single.fromCallable {
            //perform calculation
            1
        }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MyClass.performCalculation().subscribe { result ->
            //update ui
        }
    }
}
```

Using [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html):

```
object MyClass {
    fun performCalculation(): Deferred<Int> {
        return async(CommonPool) {
            //your calculation
            1
        }
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        launch(UI) {
            val result = MyClass.performCalculation().await()
            //update ui
        }
    }
}
```